# What is the name of the creature outside Jabba's Palace that gets eaten in Return of the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

Referring to a scene of a few seconds right after Chewbacca gets captured. In the shadow of Jabba's palace is a frog-like creature (a [Worrt](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Worrt)) and a small raccoon-size animal making noises kind of like a crow or a chicken clucking. The creature sees the frog, tries to run away, but the frog notices, catches the creature with its tongue, swallows it, and burps loudly.

[image]

**Does anyone know the name of the smaller creature? It looks a lot like a womp rat or a gorg, but I'm not sure.**

Also, was any of this added in a re-release? I know the [frog was in the original](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138215/was-that-frog-thing-outside-jabbas-palace-that-eats-an-animal-and-burps-in-the), but I don't recall the sounds and all in the original film and I usually notice stuff like that.

[image]

Comment: It's a jakesagierus, named after the first person who discovered it :)

Comment: It's Muad'dib, the desert mouse.  Oh wait, wrong universe.

Comment: @Stephen, there are those that believe that the Star Wars universe and the Dune universe are one in the same - just at different time periods.

Comment: @PhasedOut  sauce... that sounds like a fun fan theory to read

Comment: Womp rats. Obviously

Answer (score 15):

The [original (theatrical) script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Return-of-the-Jedi.html) refers to it thusly

> **13   EXT JABBA'S PALACE**
>   The palace is sitting in the light of the double sunset. On the road in 
>   front, a large toadlike creature flicks its tongue out for **a desert 
>   rodent** and burps in satisfaction.

The Storyboard for the sequence refers to it as a "small creature"

[image]

Comment: Nice find on the storyboard.

Comment: There are a stack of images in "The Making of Return of the Jedi" about this sequence but none of them focus on the smaller creature.

Comment: Well, at least we know it has twelve legs. ;) Actually, I wonder whether it might bear some relation to Jabba’s (probably Legends) twelve-legged combat arachnids.

Answer (score 14):

It is known as a "[sand skitter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sand_skitter/Canon)":

> The sand skitter was named by the Lucasfilm-sanctioned [Salacious B. Crumb Creature Pack - Inclusive Edition](http://www.kid4life.com/yoda2/Salacious%20B.%20Crumb%20creature%20pack.htm), by Sideshow Collectibles.

[image: Sand Skitter]

Comment: Good find. You have my +1

Answer (score 5):

### Uncertain

All we seem to know is that it’s some small, twelve-legged creature.

> As they enter the shadow of the building, **a small creature** darts
> across the road behind them, running fast on its twelve legs. But not
> fast enough!
>
> That rocky outcropping turns out to be not a rocky outcropping at all,
> but some sort of desert predator. In an instant, it has cracked open a
> huge toothy mouth, shot out a long tongue, caught, chomped…and gulped
> down the creature, **twelve legs and all**.
>
> <sub>*Beware the Power of the Dark Side!*</sub>

It’s also referred to as a “desert rodent” in the script:

> The palace is sitting in the light of the double sunset. On the road
> in front, a large toadlike creature flicks its tongue out for a desert
> rodent and burps in satisfaction.

It’s worth noting that it cannot be a [scurrier](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Scurrier/Canon), as some people believe, since it has twelve legs.

Answer (score -2):

The Correct answer is - it is a Worrt.

A worrt first appeared in the 1983 movie Star Wars: Episode VI Return of the Jedi, the third installment in the original trilogy of Star Wars. The worrt is seen capturing a sand skitter with its tongue outside the crime lord Jabba the Hutt's palace and devouring it. Like many of the creatures seen at Jabba's Palace in the movie, the worrt was portrayed by a puppet. Its production nickname was simply "road creature."

Extra - Oga's Cantina bar at Star Wars: Galaxy's Edge has an animatronic worrt above the bar.

Also seen in the 3rd episode of The Book of Boba Fett, eating again.

Comment: The question is asking for the name of the smaller creature, not the Worrt. You called the smaller creature a "sand skitter" - can you expand on that? Is that its name?

Comment: This is a [worrt](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Worrt). It's not the thing that OP is asking about.